# Nodejs login api null checking ambiguity

Tags: node.js, api

I am developing a login api using nodejs,Mysql. I want to check condition that if username and password is empty so it should give an error. i place if condition but it is not giving an error.  Here is my function code.

```
module.exports.login = (req, res) => {
var username = req.body.username;
var password = req.body.password;

if (!username || !password) {
    helper.userLogin(username)
        .then((data) => {
            if (data) {
                if (data.password == password) {
                    res.status(200).json({
                        status : 200,
                        message: 'Successfully Login'
                    })
                }
                else {
                    res.status(201).json({
                        status : 201,
                        message: 'Password is wrong',
                    })
                }
            }
            else {
                res.status(400).json({
                    status : 400,
                    message: 'error in query'
                })
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(401).json({
                status: 401,
                message: err
            })
        })
}
else {
    res.status(501).json({
        status : 501,
        message: 'Enter username and password'
    })
 }
}
```

According to function definition there should be an error when there is no username and password provided. But i am getting this error

[image]

Comment: A side note, you're already declaring the `username` and `password` variables to hold what's there in the request body, no need to refer to `req.body.username` and `req.body.password` afterwards.

Comment: The way you've structured it, you need to check for presence of `username` **and** `password`, i.e.: `if (username && password) { ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you check for empty string, you should check against `''` not `' '`

```
if (req.body.username == '' || req.body.password == '')
```

But I would do something like:

```
 if (!username || !password) {
    // If username or password are empty
    return res.status(501).json({
        status: 501,
        message: 'Enter username and password'
    })
 }

 // The rest of your code
```

Which will take care of `null/undefined/false/''`

---

### UPDATE

I'm a big fan of [superstruct](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/superstruct) for API validation. You could do something like this in order to improve readability and help you validate easily any field.

Install the package first

```
npm install superstruct
npm install validator
```

**struct.js**

```
const { superstruct } = require('superstruct');
const validator = require('validator');

// Some custom types
// You could add any type you want!
const types = {
    empty: v => !v,
    '!empty': v => !!v,
    email: v => validator.isEmail(v + ''),
    numeric: v => validator.isNumeric(v + '')
};

module.exports = superstruct({ types });
```

**route.js**

```
const struct = require('./struct');

module.exports.login = (req, res) => {

    const Schema = struct({
        username: 'string & !empty',
        password: 'string & !empty'
    });

    // All this could be abstracted and moved elswhere
    // but I leave that to you.
    const [error, parsed] = Schema.validate(req.body); // Second parameter is default values

    if(error) {

        // Bad request
        return res.status(400).json({
            status: 400,
            message: error.message
            // A very good error message
            // IE: expected 'string & !empty' for username but received ''
        });

    }

    // From this point, the request is fully validated

    // "parsed" contains the request body, but with defaults values added, if you used any
    const { username, password } = parsed;

    helper.userLogin(username)
        .then(/* ... */)

        // Continue with your code

};
```

Comment: Still same result. no progress.

Comment: Well there's something you're not telling us then :), do this: `console.log(password, username)` and post it here.

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: thanx it worked for me :) i will accept your answer in 2 minutes

Comment: Glad to help you, I'm updating my answer with something that I believe will help you validate all APIs more easily. :) (It will take me some minutes)

Comment: sure, much appreciated :)